# Run a Data Fusion pipeline only when a file exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I already have a working pipeline in Data Fusion that makes all ETL proccess but I need it to run only when it finds a file called SUCCESS.txt located in a Cloud Storage bucket. 
**Is this even possible?** 
On other platforms I used a file watcher (Every minute runs a job to verify if the file I specified exists on certain locatoin, if the file is there, it execute other jobs) but I can't find something similar. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Cloud Functions GCS triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) with a condition to call the [Data Fusion API](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#start_a_batch_pipeline) to start your pipeline **only** when the uploaded file is `SUCCESS.txt`.
Note that whether it calls the Data Fusion API or not, the function will trigger on **every file upload**.

##### When you create the Cloud Function:

##### 1. Choose the Cloud Storage trigger type and the Finalize/Create event type.

[image]

##### 2. Add the [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var) with your own values and click next.

[image]

##### 3. Set the runtime to python 3.7, the name of the python function in the entry point (In this case ,`run_pipeline`) and add your python script (or the example below) in `main.py`.

[image]

```py
import requests
import json
import os

def get_access_token():

    # scope of the API access. Limit it to just cloud platform services
    scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

    # add the scopes
    api="http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=" + scopes

    # api call to get the access token
    r = requests.get(api,headers=headers).json()

    # return the access token
    return r['access_token']

def run_pipeline(data, context):
    '''
    Calls the Data Fusion API to start the pipeline
    '''
    
    # get environmental variables set in the inital configuraiton.
    PROJECT_ID=os.environ.get('PROJECT_ID', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    TOPIC_ID=os.environ.get('TOPIC_ID', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    PIPELINE_NAME=os.environ.get('PIPELINE_NAME', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    INSTANCE_ID=os.environ.get('INSTANCE_ID', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    REGION=os.environ.get('REGION', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    NAMESPACE_ID=os.environ.get('NAMESPACE_ID', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')
    CDAP_ENDPOINT=os.environ.get('CDAP_ENDPOINT', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')

    # get uploaded file name
    file_name = data['name']
    
    # get access token
    auth_token=get_access_token()
    
    # api call full endpoint
    post_endpoint = CDAP_ENDPOINT + "/v3/namespaces/" + NAMESPACE_ID + "/apps/" + PIPELINE_NAME + "/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start"
    
    # If the pipeline has any macros that need to be set, you can pass them in as a payload
    data = '{"my-file":' + file_name +'}'
    
    # add bearer token to the header
    post_headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + auth_token,"Accept": "application/json"}
    
    # condition to start the job:
    if file_name == 'SUCCESS.txt':
        # start the job
        r1 = requests.post(post_endpoint,data=data,headers=post_headers)
```

##### 4. Deploy your function and when it is ready, test it by uploading your `SUCCESS.txt` file or any other file.

I have tested it and it works fine (Based on this [post](https://jtaras.medium.com/google-data-fusion-using-cloud-storage-file-uploads-to-trigger-data-fusion-etl-pipelines-cec3325c78e7)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! <br> Unfortunately when trying to implement it I found the organization doesn´t like Cloud Function and its disabled but I'll try a work around.

Comment: Independently of your organization's policy, if you believe this is a good answer to your question, please consider accepting it so other users may find it easier if they have the same issue.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use [Pub/Sub notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) with a [notification polling script](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/samples/snippets/notification_polling.py) but you would need to have it running all the time (unless you have a specific time range when the file is dropped in GCS).